# How to set the edited attribute to a variable in SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Basically, to be able to write fewer functions, I made the edited attribute a variable. So my editing code looks like this :

```py
cur.execute("""
                    UPDATE acteurs SET ?=? WHERE IDACTEUR=?;
                    """, (attribute, newvalue, actorid))
        conn.commit()
```

But when running it, I get a syntax error. How should I edit this to make it work?

Comment: in some places you can't use `?` for security reason. For example you can't use `?` as table name. And you may need to put some values using `string formatting` or `f-string`

Comment: @esqew Maybe it is standard substitution in SQLIte but Python may block it - for security reason

Comment: @esqew I would say that problem can be because Python may escape parameters to make them safe. So instead of `column=value` it may create two strings `"column"="value"` and this is not correct in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is escaping values before putting in query - for security reasons - so values can't be used in some places because it creates wrong query.

Using `?=?` you expect `column=value` but it creates two strings `"column"="value"` and it can generate error.

It may also check if `?` is in place for table name or column name and raise error - for security reasons.

It may need to put `column` using `string formatting` or `f-string`. But it is not preferred. Queries shouldn't use `?` for table names, column names.

---

Minimal working example.

It uses `con.set_trace_callback(print)` to display last query.

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")#
con.set_trace_callback(print)

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test(key TEXT, value TEXT)")
print('---')
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(key, value) VALUES (?, ?)", ("a", "1"))
con.commit()
print('---')

cur.execute("SELECT key, value FROM test WHERE key=?", ('a',))
row = cur.fetchone()
print(row)
print('---')

cur.execute("SELECT key, value FROM test WHERE ?=?", ('key', 'a'))
row = cur.fetchone()
print(row)
print('---')

try:
    cur.execute("UPDATE test SET ?=? WHERE key=?", ('value', '3', 'a',))
    con.commit()
except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:', ex)
print('---')

try:
    column = 'value'
    cur.execute(f"UPDATE test SET {column}=? WHERE key=?", ('3', 'a',))
    con.commit()
except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:', ex)
print('---')

cur.execute("SELECT key, value FROM test WHERE key=?", ('a',))
row = cur.fetchone()
print(row)
print('---')

con.close()
```

Example `WHERE key=?", ('a',)` creates `WHERE key='a'` and it gets one row.

Example `WHERE ?=?", ('key', 'a',)` creates `WHERE 'key'='a'` and it gets zero rows.

Example `SET ?=?` raises error.

```
CREATE TABLE test(key TEXT, value TEXT)
---
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO test(key, value) VALUES ('a', '1')
COMMIT
---
SELECT key, value FROM test WHERE key='a'
('a', '1')
---
SELECT key, value FROM test WHERE 'key'='a'
None
---
Exception: near "?": syntax error
---
BEGIN 
UPDATE test SET value='3' WHERE key='a'
COMMIT
---
SELECT key, value FROM test WHERE key='a'
('a', '3')
```

Comment: In short - you cannot use placeholder replacement for things like table and column names, as it creates a significant security risk that this type of substitution seeks to mitigate.

Comment: @esqew yes, it checks query for security risk - so queries should't use  placeholder for tables and colums